# Temporary storage for current tab only in extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension for generating passwords and outputting the phonetic version as well.
Basicly the extension creates the password and displays it in one DIV and the phonetic version in another, so if password was 'ac3', password DIV would show 'ac3' and phonetic DIV would show 'Alpha, Charley, Three'.
The problem is that as soon as I click outside the extension popup it disappears and I loose the current password.

My first attempt to sort this was to use chrome.storage.local.set after creating the password and then re-populating the password DIV via chrome.storage.local.get when you click on the extension again, this works great, but the data is available from any tab within the browser (even separate windows).
I understand that storing the password in any way is insecure, but wanted to find a way to limit the data stored to the current tab rather than globally.
I haven't found a way to keep the extension popup displayed to allow a user to copy/paste both DIVs.

Anyone got any pointers?

Also anyone able to point me in the direction of wiping the local storage value after a set amount of time? Just to make things slightly more secure.

This extension is used mainly for admin work, where you need to create a new password for a user, copy/paste it into a portal and then SMS/Email the password to the end user.

Comment: Strictly speaking there's nothing inherently "insecure" about chrome.storage.local because the data can only be accessed by your extension, not by a web page. The documentation probably confused you by using the same term "local storage", but it's not the HTML5 `window.localStorage` so it's not shared with the web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah, thanks for that, will keep the chrome.storage.local then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data stored in `chrome.storage` is only available to your own extension, so it's not any less secure than any other way of storing it.

Just store it via `chrome.storage.local.set()` and then delete it a few minutes later, if unused. You'll have to set a deletion mechanism in `background.js` via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` or `chrome.alarms`

---

I had also tried `sessionStorage` in the popup, but sadly it's lost as soon as the popup is closed. Same goes for `history.replaceState`.